# gcc acknowledging -Wfatal-errors parameter but not acting upon it

Tags: mingw-w64, g++4.9

Using the parameter, after every error gcc prints out "compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors."

But it keeps going. Does not actually stop.

I use:

```
g++ (x86_64-win32-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2
```

Calling the compiler:

```
@echo off
set LIBRARY_PATH=D:\Projekte\C++\Arsenal of Democracy\sdk\Lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2008)\Lib\x86
set CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=D:\Projekte\C++\Arsenal of Democracy\sdk\Include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2008)\Include

cd src
g++ -m32 -mwindows -w -Wfatal-errors -std=c++14 -o ../AODGame.exe *.cpp
cd ..
```

Compilation time is about the same as without the parameter. Number of errors is also the same.

**However**, if I construct a minimal example:

```
int main()
{
  cout << "Bla." << endl; // 1st error - should abort here
  t - q = v;              // 2nd error - should not reach nor report
}
```

and compile **that** with

```
g++ -Wfatal-errors -o Test Test.cpp
```

Then it **does** work and the second error never shows up (and it does without the parameter).

What might be the cause of this irregularity? How can I circumvent it?

Obviously I do not care whether compilation of a tiny example is aborted or not, but with a real project the time saved is - or rather would be - actually valuable.

I have searched for this problem and only found ~two years old topics about different problems with the same parameter (not working on Clang, not included in gcc 3.x, etc.), none of which seems to be applicable here.

--

To follow @David Macek's comment, a minimal example with the same type of first error is

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class X> void test(vector<X> & v)
{
  vector<X>::iterator i = v.begin();
}

int main()
{
  t - v = q;
}
```

It, too, correctly terminates after the very first error and never reaches the expression in main.

Comment: Just to be sure, are there multiple errors, or some warnings and then one error?

Comment: Does the minimal example produce the same errors as the game? Maybe the behaviour depends on the type of errors.

Comment: There are multiple errors. Every single one of them ends with the line "compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors".

All warnings have been disabled with the "-w" flag.

The type of errors is indeed different. A minimal example with identical first error has been added to the question. It, too, terminates correctly after the first error.